# Can't create recurring event, but a single event works

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-calendar-api

So I am one step away from finishing my web application and since recurring events would be the main appeal, I am a bit frustrated.
Even if I try creating a recurring event from the Google Calendar API template, it simply doesn't work.

Main source: https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events
This is the template I based mine on:

```
var event = {
  'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
  },
  'end': {
    'dateTime': '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
  },
  'recurrence': [
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ],
};

var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
  'calendarId': 'primary',
  'resource': event
});

request.execute(function(event) {
  appendPre('Event created: ' + event.htmlLink);
});
```

Note:

```
  let event = {
    'summary': title[0], //Name of the show, type: string
    'colorId': '2',
    'description': 'New episode of '+ title[0],
    'start': {
      'dateTime': `${initDate}T${hours}:${minutes}:00+09:00`,
      //Example: '2019-06-17T01:30:00+09:00' 
    },
    'end': {
      'dateTime': `${initDate}T${hourAndMin(hours,minutes)}+09:00`,
      //Same but with +30 mins example: '2019-06-17T02:00:00+09:00'
    },
    'recurrence': [
      'RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20190717' //Example 1 month weekly
      //I have also tried the exact line from the template.
    ],
  };

  let request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
    'calendarId': 'primary',
    'resource': event
  });
  request.execute(function(event) {
    if (event.htmlLink === undefined){
      alert('Error.')
    } else {
      alert('Event created in your Google Calendar.');
    }
  });
```

When I remove the 'recurrence' part it works, but if I leave it there I get a POST 400 Bad Request Error in the browser console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is pretty explicit in the requirement to provide [only one timezone](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#recurring_event_time_zones) for recurrence.

I believe there is a conflict in your timeZone calculation. Your dateTime suggests `-07:00` but `America/Los_Angeles` is currently `-08:00`. It might be best to leave the timeZone differential off the value in the dateTime attribute for start and end. That way, Google can determine the offset whether Daylight Savings Time is in effect or not.

Comment: Oh my, thank you so much, it worked. I couldn't have figured it out on my own.

Comment: Great! I'm glad that was the problem. Sometimes all it takes is a second pair of eyes